# oci_bind_by_name and value-type issue or how to debug

Tags: php, oracle

We use oracle-databases. For my webapplication I wrote a little database-helper-class to provide select, update and insert methods and have less (and non-redundant) code. But sometimes the results of the queries are not as expected or INSERTs throwing errors because of wrong literals, but the assigned values are correct.

```
public function selectQuery($sqlString, $values2bind = null){
    $sqlResource = $this->queryWrapper($sqlString, $values2bind);
    $rows = [];
    if($sqlResource) {
        while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($sqlResource)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        oci_free_statement($sqlResource);
        return $rows;
    }
    oci_free_statement($sqlResource);
    return false;
}
private function queryWrapper($sqlString, $values2bind){
    $sql = oci_parse($this->connection, $sqlString);
    if(is_array($values2bind)){
        foreach($values2bind as $key=>$value){
            oci_bind_by_name($sql, ":".$key, $value);
        }
    }
    if (!($sql)){
        $e = oci_error($this->connection);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'].$e["sqltext"], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        error_log($e['message'].$e["sqltext"]);
        return false;
    }
    $r = oci_execute($sql);
    if(!$r){
        $e = oci_error($this->connection);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'].$e["sqltext"], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        error_log($e['message'].$e["sqltext"]);
        return false;
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

As example I call it like

```
$selectSQL = "SELECT to_char(SPZ_GILT_AB, 'DD.MM.YYYY') as INTERVALL_START, 
                         to_char(SPZ_GILT_BIS, 'DD.MM.YYYY') as INTERVALL_END
                  FROM SPZ_BLOCK 
                  WHERE ID = :id 
                    AND BID = :bid 
                    AND (SPZ_GILT_AB > sysdate OR (SPZ_GILT_AB < sysdate AND SPZ_GILT_BIS > sysdate))";
$intervals = $this->db->selectQuery($selectSQL, array('bid' => $bid, 'id' => $id));
```

$id and $bid are both strings of numbers (i.e. 2524 and 5627). 
BID und ID have databse-type NUMBER(10,0).

But here something strange happens. If I remove $bid, it works. If $bid is used, it does not work.

It would be nice to see the statement which is executed, but I think thats not possible.

Any idea baout that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's all about the caching of oci_bind_by_name()...
After a lot of try&fail I got it to work by giving oci_bind_by_name not the $value itself, but the reference to &$value!

```
private function queryWrapper($sqlString, $values2bind){
    $sql = oci_parse($this->connection, $sqlString);
    if(is_array($values2bind)){
        foreach($values2bind as $key => &$value){           // <- &$value instead of $value
            oci_bind_by_name($sql, ":".$key, $value);
        }
    }
    if (!($sql)){
        $e = oci_error($this->connection);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'].$e["sqltext"], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        error_log($e['message'].$e["sqltext"]);
        return false;
    }
    $r = oci_execute($sql);
    if(!$r){
        $e = oci_error($this->connection);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'].$e["sqltext"], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        error_log($e['message'].$e["sqltext"]);
        return false;
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: A related example is "Example #3 Binding with a foreach() loop" in the [oci_bind_by_name() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php).